# "I want to read this book" and "I want to be reading this book"

Tags: grammar

I would like to ask about the difference in meaning of 2 following sentences:

- I want to read this book
- I want to be reading this book

I understand that both generally mean "want to do someething" but also think that there should be some difference here.

Especially with the second sentence, I encounter the structure **"to be V-ing"** a tons of times but don't really get it, e.g. "I will be singing/talking...." ; "Tell me what you'd like to be doing right now..." to name just a few.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to read this book.

This means that, at some point in time, and perhaps not all at once, you want to read the whole book. Perhaps you will read a chapter a day.

---

> I want to be reading this book.

This means that you want to be engaged in the act of reading the book right now.